# Bootstrap radio button in bootstrap without styling not changable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html page with 2 radio buttons ('on' and 'off' where 'off' is the default) that has no styling whatsoever.
This works fine if I'm not including bootstrap javascript. As soon as I include it in the head, the radio-button doesn't work anymore. I can not change it from 'off' to 'on'.
I do not want to style this one because my users are accustomed to the radio buttons being circles :-(

Marcel

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bs.js">
</head>
<body>
....
<form id="config" method="post">
....
<input type="radio" name="DHCP" id="DHCP_OFF" value="DHCP_OFF" checked>off
<input type="radio" name="DHCP" id="DHCP_ON" value="DHCP_ON">on
....
</form>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap's handling of radio buttons doesn't really seem to do much to them (see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls). Your question could do with a code example. Even better would be a jsFiddle demo

Comment: My mistake about the closing quotes. I copied it in parts (on my phone :-( ) and forgot the quotes...

Comment: So how is it not working? Any errors in your browser console? Can you create a jsFiddle demo illustrating the problem? I've recreated your form code here with both Bootstrap JS and CSS and it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/k6pqt/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the part that is not in the code.
I had data-toggle="button-radio" on the div around the radio buttons.